# How to implement smooth tile based movement

Tags: python, pygame

The player in my game is centered in the screen, and I 'scroll' the background to move around.

I get a list of keys pressed with  `pygame.key.get_pressed()`, if the player's move cooldown is over, I call a move function. This function scrolls the map in the direction of movement for one tile.

However the movement is not smooth. It 'jumps' to the next tile.

How do I implement a movement system so that the player moves in small steps (speed * dt) but still only moves the distance of one tile every time the move function is called? The game needs to be rendered in between each small step I think.

Full source here: https://github.com/HCollings/rpg-game/blob/alternate_movement/game.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animations and movement are all about what you perceive rather than what's actually happening. In a grid system, you can abstract the visual movement of the player away from the actual mechanics by taking the drawing part of the code and updating the draw position independently of the gameplay position.

The problem you are experiencing with jumping is commonly handled with some kind of interpolation technique. lerp() is a common function that provides linear interpolation, but in my below example I will use a different technique.

Here is a resource about interpolation techniques: http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/interpolation/

You could implement your movement as destination, direction, and "unspent" increments of movement.
If you wanted to move to a new square, you would set your direction and add a standard number of increments (representing one square) to your "unspent increment counter". Then you draw your graphic at the new location offset by the number of increments you still have. If you want to move more than one square at a time, then you would increase the number of unspent increments.

Movement would only take place so long as you have unspent increments (think movement points). This technique also lends itself to visual collision detection; if the remaining number of increments is some fraction of the total increments (~25%?) between the number of squares you are moving, then the graphic is "practically" in the square according to what the player sees.

Comment: Thank you, I have basically implemented this. move -> points = 64. render -> change bg.rect and points -= 1.